# Unity resolve dependency based on caller based class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following situation :

```
public class Animal 
{
    public virtual string SayHello(IDefaultService service)
    {
        return service.GenerateHelloString();
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public override string SayHello(ISpecializedServiceA service)
    {
        return service.GenerateHelloString();
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override string SayHello(ISpecializedServiceB service)
    {
        return service.GenerateHelloString();
    }
}

public interface IDefaultService 
{
    string GenerateHelloString();
}

public interface ISpecializedServiceA : IDefaultService 
{
    string GenerateHelloString();
}

public interface ISpecializedServiceB : IDefaultService 
{
    string GenerateHelloString();
}
```

I am going to retrieve the objects with something like that :

```
Animal animal = db.GetAnimalByID(someID);
```

And I need to do something like that :

```
animal.SayHello(mycontainer.Resolve<IDefaultService>());
```

But I would like to inject the right specialized service depending on the type of the animal.

How can I achieve that ?

Edit : this is just an illustration of the situation I'm facing, I am trying to achieve that because different specialization of my base class, will need different services to make their calls to different APIs. I'd like to know if it is possible to handle this situation with Unity and if yes how.